# Keytweak / Sharpkeys on Windows Doesn't Rekey

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-10-v1607, remapping

I lost my beloved Q key a few months back. I changed Q to an extra key on my keyboard, but when I updated to Anniversary (1607), I lost my key, which I have since been unable to change back using KeyTweak and then Sharpkeys. I suspect my registry is being "repaired" when I start my computer. Is there any way I can fix this problem?

Comment: I can confirm the same issue has happened to me. At the risk of turning this into an MS-bashing thread, I am going to be rolling back to Win 8.1 unless someone has another option. I'd prefer to stay on 10, though.

Comment: Are you OK with workaround using the AutoHotKey? AHK macro `a::b` remaps key A to B. This way you can remap your beloved Q key as before.

Answer (score 8):

**Solution 1: AutoHotkey Remapping**

AutoHotkey can be used for [Remapping Keys and Buttons](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).  However, consider AutoHotkey's limitation below.

The script `Capslock::q` would make the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> behave like  <kbd>Q</kbd>.

> Limitation: AutoHotkey's remapping feature described below is
>   generally not as pure and effective as remapping directly via the
>   Windows registry. For the advantages and disadvantages of each
>   approach, see [registry remapping](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#registry).

**Solution 2: Modify Keyboard Layout**

[Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboardlayouts.aspx) can "modify an existing keyboard layout and build a new layout from it." Since a keyboard layout is handled at a system level, it should be more compatible (than AutoHotkey) with all applications.

Note: Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator does not specifically support Windows 8, 8.1, or 10.  Users have had mixed success applying a new layout (Source: [Custom keyboard layout with Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/custom-keyboard-layout-with-windows-10/b71c7905-1e30-4b0c-861b-253efd2b5a9e?auth=1)).  One user recommended a third-party application [Keyboard Layout Manager](http://www.klm32.com/) which creates more compatible layouts.

Comment: It seems that registry mapping is not possible with windows 10, after restarting none of the changes are retained.

Comment: @keeg Then, will AutoHotkey work for you?

Comment: I tried but it just screws up the keys, its like they are pressed in and never release, had to reboot to get rid of it.

Comment: I have used AutoHotkey for years without issue.  If you close AutoHotkey (from the tray icon), behavior should return to normal.

Comment: I will try it again...

Comment: MKLC does not work on Windows 10.

Comment: A missing info: Sharpkeys (open source) seems to work well (on all windows version) to remap keys (it uses the registry): https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys